# How can I reduce Jenkins master/slave communication?

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, master-slave

I have set up a Jenkins master (linux) and slave (Windows) on Amazon EC2. My build is running on the slave and it is considerably slower than what I was seeing on a similar desktop machine (c4.large).

Checking into the load on the slave, neither the CPU cores, nor the memory is fully used (CPU at 60%, 30% each, memory stable at about 2.5GB)

However, I'm starting to think the bottleneck is in the network traffic. I can see that there seems to be a lot of network traffic going on between master and slave. It averages at about 500Kbs going out and 250Kbs coming in, but there are regular spikes going into the multiple Mbs.

I've searched around, but I can't really figure out what data Jenkins is sending.

The job is doing quite a bit of logging, but this is not the only source. There's a console log of about 15MB for a 2 hour build, which would translate to roughly (15*1024*8)/(2*60*60) = 17Kbs

So my questions:

- What else is Jenkins communicating between master and slaves?
- How can I reduce this?

---

Update: Just to be sure, I disabled all logging during the build. And it turns out that was the source of the traffic. I don't understand why there's so much traffic given my calculations above. Maybe there's some kind of polling/acknowledging going on that's causing a lot of overhead, I still don't know.

It's apparently also not the main source of the slowdown, but still, I would like to find a way to reduce this network traffic as this is going to impact the AWS bill.

Comment: Are you archiving artifacts? This will be sent between slave and master too.

Comment: @MaTePe no, I'm not doing that at the moment. The network traffic is constant throughout the build. If it was the archiving, I would expect a spike at the end. In the mean time, I've done some additional research and will add it to my question.

Comment: Did you figure this issue out? We are seeing a very similar issue in Jenkins

Comment: @Ichaival Not really. I still don't have an explanation for the excessive traffic. However, after more experimentation, I came to the conclusion that the network traffic wasn't the main source of the slowdown anyway.